# sp_executesql Dynamically Store Queries in column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Using sp_executesql i would like to execute the results of a column that stores pre written queries on a column as show below.

```
DECLARE @ID AS INT =2
DECLARE @StoredQueries Table
(
ID INT IDENTITY(1,1),
ExtractSQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
)

INSERT INTO @StoredQueries
VALUES(
 'SELECT [DepartmentID]
      ,[Name]
      ,[GroupName]
      ,[ModifiedDate]
  FROM [AdventureWorks2008R2].[HumanResources].[Department]'
       )
INSERT INTO @StoredQueries
VALUES(
 'SELECT[ShiftID]
      ,[Name]
      ,[StartTime]
      ,[EndTime]
      ,[ModifiedDate]
  FROM [AdventureWorks2008R2].[HumanResources].[Shift]
  '
         )

INSERT INTO @StoredQueries
VALUES(
 'SELECT TOP 1000 [AddressID]
      ,[AddressLine1]
      ,[AddressLine2]
      ,[City]
      ,[StateProvinceID]
      ,[PostalCode]
      ,[SpatialLocation]
      ,[rowguid]
      ,[ModifiedDate]
  FROM [AdventureWorks2008R2].[Person].[Address]'
       )
  SELECT * FROM @StoredQueries  
  WHERE ID =@ID
```

Results from Dave.Gugg answer

```
DECLARE @ID AS INT =2
DECLARE @StoredQueries Table
(
ID INT IDENTITY(1,1),
ExtractSQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
)

INSERT INTO @StoredQueries
VALUES(
 'SELECT [DepartmentID]
      ,[Name]
      ,[GroupName]
      ,[ModifiedDate]
  FROM [AdventureWorks2008R2].[HumanResources].[Department]'
       )
INSERT INTO @StoredQueries
VALUES(
 'SELECT[ShiftID]
      ,[Name]
      ,[StartTime]
      ,[EndTime]
      ,[ModifiedDate]
  FROM [AdventureWorks2008R2].[HumanResources].[Shift]
  '
         )

INSERT INTO @StoredQueries
VALUES(
 'SELECT TOP 1000 [AddressID]
      ,[AddressLine1]
      ,[AddressLine2]
      ,[City]
      ,[StateProvinceID]
      ,[PostalCode]
      ,[SpatialLocation]
      ,[rowguid]
      ,[ModifiedDate]
  FROM [AdventureWorks2008R2].[Person].[Address]'
       )

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @sql = ExtractSQL
FROM @StoredQueries
WHERE ID = @ID

EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```

Comment: been a while, but did you try just putting the query into a variable and then exec @myVar ?

Comment: is this multiple execution ? or only one row will be executed ?

Comment: I will be adding this on a stored procedure and depending the @ID number add,this should be one query at a time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're close, just replace that very last select with this:

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @sql = ExtractSQL
FROM @StoredQueries
WHERE ID = @ID

EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```